# How do you put multiple paragraphs in a caption?

Tags: errors, captions, paragraphs

I have a really long caption for a figure in a LaTeX document.  I would like to break the caption into a few paragraphs.  How do I do that?

As per the request below, I removed everything I could while still getting the errors I mentioned in my comment.  The resulting file is this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\graphicspath{{./Figures/}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{NodesEdgesExample2.pdf}
\caption{
Paragraph 1.  

Paragraph 2.

Paragraph 3.
}
\label{fig:AltNavigationConcept}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

We're building it in TeXnicCenter, and I verified that another person in my research lab also gets the same errors on his computer with the above code.

Comment: There's no restriction that I know of.

Comment: @egreg I didn't think there was either... But, my friend's document compiles with no errors when there aren't blank lines in his caption. When we put blank lines in to separate paragraphs, it's giving errors like `Paragraph ended before \NR@gettitle was complete`, `Paragraph ended before \addcontentsline was complete` and `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please, try preparing a minimal example.

Comment: NR@gettitle appears to be from nameref package. Presumably `\def\NR@gettitle#1{%` should be `\long\def\NR@gettitle#1{%` to allow paragraphs.

Comment: I was wrong; however, if you say `\endgraf` instead of leaving a blank line, everything works. It's better, though, to follow lockstep's advice of providing a "short caption".

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The following quote from the manual of the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package (p. 12) is also true for the LaTeX standard definition of `\caption`:

> If your caption contains more than one paragraph, you have to specify
>   an alternative caption for the list-of-figures using the optional
>   argument of `\caption` or `\captionof`, otherwise you will get an
>   error message.

EDIT: To clarify: A multi-paragraph figure caption without a single-paragraph optional variant will produce an error *even if you don't use `\listoffigures` in your document*.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{foo}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption[LoF entry]{The first paragraph of a figure's caption.

And the second.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding `[LoF entry]` seems to have done the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could just put `\newline` in the front, when you want to start a new paragraph in captions. It works for me.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What does your answer distinguish to the already present answers?

Comment: @Tiuri Please do not edit posts from the low quality review queue unless you can substantially improve them. Posts that are edited are automatically removed from the queue which defeats the purpose of reviews.

Comment: @StefanPinnow My answer gives an easier way to solve this problem! It's the simplest way so far!

Comment: @samcarter It was my intention to remove the post from the queue, for I was of the opinion that no reason for deleting an answer applied.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `caption` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\captionsetup{margin={15pt},parskip=10pt,format=hang,indention=-.8cm}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{myfigure}
\caption[my caption]{\lipsum[1-2]}
\end{figure}
This is regular text. \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note**: If your caption contains at least two paragraphs, then you should add a short title `[my caption]` in `\caption[my caption]{\lipsum[1-2]}`for LOF. Otherwise it will give an error.