# Indent further paragraphs in the caption of a table

Tags: tables, floats, captions, indentation, paragraphs

I have a little problem how to create a caption to my table. It looks ok as of now, but I would like to indent the heading of a new paragraph. Also right now, I cannot even create a new paragraph because an error pops up. I read that I have to give an optional argument to the caption to prevent the error (is there another method? I don't want to have additional names in my LOT)

But my main question is if it is possible to start new intendet paragraphs within a caption, BUT WITHOUT having the very first paragraph below the numbering indented. There is no such example in the documentation of the package `caption`, also `\DeclareCaptionFormat`does not work in this case because we don't wanna change `#3` in general but rather the following paragraphs.

If you compile my example you will see a nice little table. Again, the only change I would like to make is indentation of further paragraphs in case of rather long captions.

Thanks for any hints.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, headsepline, smallheadings]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, labelsep=newline,singlelinecheck=false,format=plain,indention=2cm]{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading}
\setcapindent{0em}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htpb]
\begin{floatrow}
\ttabbox{%
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{xax} \\
\cmidrule(rl){2-5}
& 3543 & 34535 & 1233 & 32525 \\
\midrule
AA  & 543235sdgf35 & sdf35sf & sf35 & sdfsf543s \\
BB  & gsfg35sf & dfgdfg &
235sf & 235f \\
CC & sdfdsf & sffsf & sdfsdf & 353w5fs \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
{\caption{Here is the table caption. It should be indented from the following paragraph: \\ 'indented new paragraph'.}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

edit: I am using the floatrow-package because it allows you to start the caption in the next line below the numbering of the table.
ttabbox has 2 arguments, the 1st is the table and the 2nd is the caption, that's really all there is to know about that, looks more complicated than it is.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Thanks for providing an example to work with :) Have you looked at the `hang` option?

Comment: @cmhughes Hi, thank you. Yes I have, but I think it works from the very first paragraph already. My problem is I only want it to work from the second.
Ideally, you could choose which paragraphs to indent and which not to.

Comment: Inserting something like `\hspace*{1em}` after ``\\`` inside the `\caption` might be a solution?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48307/how-do-you-put-multiple-paragraphs-in-a-caption

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the few situations where paragraphs need to be closed with `\endgraf` instead of `\par`.  You also need to set `\parindent` to a non-zero length:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, headsepline, smallheadings]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, labelsep=newline,singlelinecheck=false,format=plain,indention=2cm]{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading}
\setcapindent{0em}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htpb]
  \begin{floatrow}
    \ttabbox{%
    \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
      & \multicolumn{4}{c}{xax} \\
      \cmidrule(rl){2-5}
      & 3543 & 34535 & 1233 & 32525 \\
      \midrule
      AA  & 543235sdgf35 & sdf35sf & sf35 & sdfsf543s \\
      BB  & gsfg35sf & dfgdfg &
      235sf & 235f \\
      CC & sdfdsf & sffsf & sdfsdf & 353w5fs \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
    {\caption{Here is the table caption. It should be indented from the
    following paragraph: \endgraf\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
    `indented new paragraph' with more text, a little more text and
    some words. \endgraf
    Another paragraph.}} 
  \end{floatrow}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You will find some discussion of `\endgraf` at [When is it better to use \par than \endgraf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96865/15925)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that some of the macros governing the typesetting of the caption aren't `\long`, that is, they don't accept `\par` in their argument.

A quick workaround is to add an empty optional argument to `\caption`, which however would be bad if you want to typeset the list of tables.

A different workaround is to say

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\captionpar}{\par}
```

in the preamble and use `\captionpar` instead of `\par` or an empty line in the caption. This hides `\par` from TeX's eyes when it's absorbing the argument; it's similar to using `\endgraf`, the difference is that ultimately the “real” `\par` will be used (`\endgraf` might not have the current meaning of `\par`).

A more drastic solution is to make the relevant commands `\long`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd[\long]{\caption@prepareanchor}{}{}{}{}
\patchcmd[\long]{\caption@@@addcontentsline}{}{}{}{}
\patchcmd[\long]{\addcontentsline}{}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

With this patch you can even type

```
\caption{Here is the table caption. It should be indented from
         the following paragraph:

         'indented new paragraph'.}
```

instead of the more awkward

```
\caption{Here is the table caption. It should be indented from
         the following paragraph:\captionpar
         'indented new paragraph'.}
```

required by the solution above.

In any case, you need to define a parindent for the caption:

```
\usepackage[
  labelfont=bf,
  labelsep=newline,
  singlelinecheck=false,
  format=plain,
  indention=2cm,
  parindent=1em, % <--- adjust to suit
]{caption}
```

[image]