# Newline in caption in amsart

Tags: errors, captions, paragraphs, amsart

This answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48313/38588) explains how to eliminate the error from a newline inside a caption for a figure.  However, this does not work when using the amsart document class.  Example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
blah
\caption[lh]{
Paragraph 1.

Paragraph 2.
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How do I produce a new paragraph in a caption in an amsart document?

Comment: replace the empty line with `\endgraf`. But seriously, more than one paragraph in a caption? Don't you think that information is better suited in the main text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

arguably this is a bug in  amsart, you can avoid it by allowing paragraphs in the latex command it uses

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\makeatletter
\long\def\@cdr#1#2\@nil{#2}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
blah
\caption[lh]{
Paragraph 1.

Paragraph 2.
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

`amsart` defines `\@makecaption` explictly using `\long` so that paragraphs are allowed, but at one point calls `\@cdr` (which just discards one token or brace group) but that is not long do you get the error you report.

A longer term fix is probably to leave `\@cdr` as it is and define say `\@longcdr` as above then use `\@longcdr` in the definition of `\@maketitle` in `amsart.cls`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes but not in \caption, which usually allows \par in latex,  and amsart.cls has `\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%` that `\long` is only there to allow paragraphs in the caption. but then it drops to the low level \@cdr and erorrs there. If the intention is not to allow paragraphs then `\@makecaption` should not be long and you'd get a better error message.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- oops!  i misread that as `\footnote`, not `\caption`.  it does legitimately belong in the list of concerns about ams document classes, and i'll make sure it's there.  but it will cause a secondary problem: like chapter and section titles in the toc, the full form of a caption is put into a list of figures.  that's a rather thorny problem that will have to be considered.

Comment: @barbarabeeton that's addressed in the referenced answer to which this is a followup, put a one-line short version in the optional argument for the list of figures. That works for the standard classes (and memoir etc) but the question here points out it fails for amsart.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- yes.  the decision to use the "long form" in the frontmatter tables is an editorial style decision.  it's ams style of (very) long standing.  we often see additional text following a figure, and simply remove it from the caption, leaving it within the float.  (some additional styling may be necessary.)  quite a few other things about captions are documented in the ams author handbook, but not this.  i'll look into that too.

Comment: @barbarabeeton oh sorry I see what you mean, ah so it's probably a bad idea to have multi-paragraph captions in amsart anyway, but failing in `\@cdr` maybe isn't the best way to flag that:-)